# Game not ending when I crash into the obstacle

Tags: python, pygame

I have to complete this project for tomorrow so if anyone could please help me, I would appreciate it. When I take out the code for making the game harder (see comment in the code) the game over works. But when I add that part, even when you hit the obstacle the game keeps running. Please let me know how I can fix this problem. Thank you.

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.font.init
WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)

FPS = 40
BADDIEMINSIZE = 100
BADDIEMAXSIZE = 100
BADDIEMINSPEED = 8
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 60
PLAYERMOVERATE = 10

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('crash.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.wav')

# set up images
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
bg = pygame.image.load('mud.jpg')
playerImage = pygame.image.load('Picture1.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('Picture2.png')

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Dodger', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    baddies = []
    score = 0
    level = 1
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    baddieAddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            baddieAddCounter += 1
        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieAddCounter = 0
            baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
            newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                        }

            baddies.append(newBaddie)

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for b in baddies:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                baddies.remove(b)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        screen.blit(bg, (0,0))

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)
        drawText('Level: %s' % (level), font, windowSurface, 10, 80)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie
        for b in baddies:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()


        #Make game harder if player is doing well
        if score>=500 and score<1000:
                BADDIEMINSPEED = 10
                BADDIEMAXSPEED = 10
                drawText('LEVEL 2', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
                pygame.display.update()

        elif score>=1000 and score <1500:
                BADDIEMINSPEED = 20
                BADDIEMAXSPEED = 20
                drawText('LEVEL 3', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
                pygame.display.update()

        elif score>=1500 and score<2000:
                BADDIEMINSPEED = 30
                BADDIEMAXSPEED = 30
                drawText('LEVEL 4', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
                pygame.display.update()

        elif score>=2000 and score<3000:
                BADDIEMINSPEED = 40
                BADDIEMAXSPEED = 40
                drawText('LEVEL 5', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
                pygame.display.update()

        elif score>=3000:
                BADDIEMINSPEED = 50
                BADDIEMAXSPEED = 50
                drawText('LEVEL 6', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
                pygame.display.update()      

        mainClock.tick(int(FPS))

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score


            # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            gameOverSound.play()

            drawText('You have Crashed!', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
            drawText('Press any key to play again', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
            pygame.display.update()
            waitForPlayerToPressKey()

            gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: Check your indentation for the 7 lines at the end of the file.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to call `pygame.display.update()` when you change the level, you might be causing the game to wait for an extra frame. Also, your collision logic just might not work at higher framerates, because the player might pass all the way through an enemy before the next collision check, sometimes that happens unfortunately.

Comment: you have to leave `while True` loop - if you had `while running` you could use `running = False`

Comment: oh..that could be the problem Marius. Thanks for that...what do you think I should do instead?

Comment: Move the level changing code somewhere in between where you blit the background and where you update the display, and remove the `pygame.display.update()` calls from each level change, see if that works better.

Comment: So marius..i changed the whole fps thing by making the speed of the cars only move faster instead of the framerate but still the game doesn't end when i crash into the car.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter way too early with my previous comment.  Thought I had finished saying what I needed to say; see edit

Comment: FAWFUL!!! You were right! that fixed it! thank you so much! If I have anymore questions can i just ask you please?

Comment: You're supposed to put it inside the `if` statement; that code never runs if it's after a `while True:` loop

Comment: so i did what you said fawful and it worked..well kinda. The whole game over thing pops up but now when you press a key to try again.. the game just continues from where you crashed and keeps on going.

Comment: You have to set up the game again; use `break` to get out of the inner `while True:` and reset the game.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
        if score > topScore:
            topScore = score # set new top score


        # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gameOverSound.play()

        drawText('You have Crashed!', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
        drawText('Press any key to play again', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
        pygame.display.update()
        waitForPlayerToPressKey()

        gameOverSound.stop()
```

For the above, you can call `terminate()` at the very end of the `if` statement to force the game to quit and stop... permanently.